# How to create an average value for every cell which contains a certain phrase?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I need to find the average value of cells containing a certain set of initials to create a scoreboard.

The value of the cell being the score and the brackets containing the initials of the score setter.

[image: Here is the table I am referring to.]

So the goal is to create an average score for each of the players (HG), (GT) & (JT).

I have tried different ways of combining `REGEXMATCH` and `REGEXEXTRACT` to no avail.

I don't mind using multiple cells if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=query(ArrayFormula(split(regexreplace( 
                      query(flatten(A2:C),"where Col1 is not null"),"\(|\)","")," ")),
           "select Col2, avg(Col1) group by Col2 label Col2 'Players', avg(Col1) 'Average' ",0)
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs.)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)